# How can I get Site Title in Sakai

Tags: jsp, sakai

Is there any way to get the current site title in the JSP page?tt

I need it to send the information to a SOAP webservice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I've solved it with this code.

```
SiteService si= new SiteService();
si.getSite(sakaiProxy.getCurrentSiteId()).getTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though you'll need to inject the ToolManager API into your application.
You then call `toolManager.getCurrentPlacement().getContext()` to get the Site object, and from there, `getTitle()`.

Comment: How can I do to inject the ToolManager into the application? This is my first time with jsp.

Comment: Ok. I have ToolManager API, but getContext() doesn't have a getTitle() method.

Comment: You can get the current site from that. You get the title from the org.sakaiproject.site.api.Site object.